# alternatives to >$120 replacement clock for old Magic Chef gas range

Tags: oven, plastic, range

I'm looking for ideas to avoid paying over $120 to replace the clock on my old gas range where the electronics are working but the plastic attachments are broken.

My Magic Chef Model #31211WAW has a simple digital clock/timer panel that just broke. The electronics work fine, but the panel is attached with screws to the oven with 4 small plastic pieces that have broken under repeated finger-pressing pressure over decades.

The [part #74004946 that's been replaced by #74006099](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/part-number/74004946/0022/464) costs over $120. Ouch!  I'm loath to replace it if I can just fix the attachment problem.

Is there a good way to reinforce what's left of the plastic attachment points so that the clock will stay attached to the metal ribs that in turn attach to the oven?  It can be ugly since none of this is visible-- but needs to be strong enough to withstand hundreds of pokes per month from harried cooks in our house and the nearby radiant heat of hot pots on the stove.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way I have fixed things like this is to form new tabs out of metal parts. Have the new tabs bend down inside the back side of the plastic bezel piece where you use a good two part epoxy to glue the metal part in place.

For where the plastic tab may still be intact you can add a thinner metal piece and glue into place in the same manner to strengthen the remaining part.

I've had really the best luck using copper plate material for this because it is easy to work with and bends nice without cracking like aluminum does. Soft brass plate works too but is harder to work with. Use steel wool to clean away tarnish to allow the epoxy to stick better.